Derashos Chasam Sofer on הגבלת of Har Sinai
In sefer Beirach Moshe Al HaTorah (Vol. 4, Bamidbar, Parshas Naso, p. 38), the Beirach Moshe of Satmar, Rabbi Moshe Teitelbaum quotes a Chasam Sofer in his Derashos Chasam Sofer about the Hagbalah of Har Sinai (Shemos 19:12). There, the Torah says:

And thou shalt set bounds to the people round about, saying, Take heed to yourselves, that you go not up into the mountain, or touch the border of it: whoever touches the mountain shall be surely put to death:

The Chasam Sofer is quoted:

מרן החתם סופר בדרשותיו לחג השבועות עמוד רפת כי מטעם זה הוזהרו ישראל בשעת קבלת התורה על מצות הגבלה שתי פעמים כי מקודם נאמר שמות יט י"ב והגבלת את העם סביב לאמר היינו הגבלה גשמית כפשוטו לצל ילכו בגופם אל ההר ושוב אחר כך נאמר שמות יט כ"א ויאמר ה' אל משה רד העד בעם פן יהרסו אל ה' לראו"ת והוא הגבלה רוחנית לצל יציצו בעין שכלם בעיון וחקירה עכ"ד
Maran the Chasam Sofer wrote in his Derashos for Shavuos (p. 286) that
for this reason, the Israelites were warned about the mitzvah of
setting boundaries (hagbalah) twice during the giving of the Torah.
Initially, it is written in Shemos 19:12, 'And you shall set
boundaries for the people all around, saying,' which refers to a
physical boundary, as understood simply, so they would not approach
the mountain with their bodies. Then later, it is written in Shemos
19:21, 'And the L-rd said to Moshe: Go, warn the people, lest they
break through to gaze upon the L-rd,' which refers to a spiritual
boundary, so they would not gaze with the eyes of their intellect
through excessive investigation and inquiry. Thus concluded his
words."

I checked online, but could not find this specific explanation in the writings of the Chasam Sofer. Does anyone know what the exact location is of this piece from the Chasam Sofer?

I think it should say רפח instead of רפת, and לבל instead of לצל (twice), but I don't have Berach Moshe to check, does it appear that way in the original?

@ba it may not be a accurate translation, still wip :)

This is found in Drashot Chatam Sofer vol. 2 p. 288a (bottom of first column).

Thank you very much. What exactly is the meaning of "spiritual boundaries" in relation to Avodas Hashem? Does the Chasam Sofer also say this? As I read it, it only refers to refrain from looking at forbidden things.

@Shmuel The Chatam Sofer is saying the second one is putting up boundaries to improper thoughts or intellectual investigation, or possibly even literal sight, improperly looking at the divine presence, like the elders and Nadav and Avihu (Shemot 24:11).

Thanks, but could it also refer to Avodas Hashem?

@Shmuel He's talking about עיון, looking, or intellectual investigation (which is also how the Berach Moshe takes it). The lesson would apparently be to hold yourself back from investigating God without restraint or casually. If you're looking specifically for the perspective of avoda, try looking at the Rambam (More Nevuchim 1:5 and elsewhere) who expresses the same idea in that kind of way.

Thank you very much :)
